# Cumulative sum without going below zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following scores

```
 RatingID | UserID| Score | 
   1      |   1   |   2   | 
   2      |   1   |   3   | 
   3      |   1   |   -8  | 
   4      |   1   |   6   | 
   5      |   2   |   3   |
```

What I am looking for is a cumulative SUM in SQL Server (2012 onwards) whereby it ignores the a negative floor i.e. the SUM cannot go below zero.  So in the case of the above, it would be *2 + 3= 5, + -8 = 0, + 6 = 6*. So the output I want is

```
 UserID | Score | 
    1   |   6   | 
    2   |   3   |
```

I have explored loops and cursors but these are proving to be inefficient on large selects.  Is there any other alternative in MSSQL?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You need to do this using a recursive CTE, which is quite expensive if you have large data.

Comment: No sequence or timestamp column or similar?

Comment: can you show your desired results....As I'm not clear

Comment: Without a column to order by, this is currently impossible. With the data you have supplied, you can't achieve your goal reliably.

Comment: An observation: Processing the data *in some order* is important: if the -8 is first, you ignore it completely. If last, then you need to use it fully

Comment: @jarih - Identity column added, this can be used for the ordering

Comment: @Larnu - Identity column added this can be used for the ordering

Answer (score 1):

The example below includes an ID, because you need something to order the scores in the cummulative sum.

It uses a recursive CTE with a special rule for the cummulative sum.

A SQL Fiddle can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/86641/1/0)

**Example snippet:**

```
declare @Scores table (ID int identity(1,1) primary key, UserID int, Score int);

insert into @Scores (UserId, Score) values
(1,2),
(1,3),
(1,-8),
(1,6),
(2,3);

with CTE as
(
  select ID, UserId, Score,
  row_number() over (partition by UserID order by ID) as RN,
  row_number() over (partition by UserID order by ID desc) as reverseRN
  from @Scores
)
, RCTE as
(
  select ID, UserId, Score, RN, reverseRN, 
   iif(Score>=0,Score,0) as SpecialCummSum
  from CTE 
  where RN = 1

  union all

  select c.ID, c.UserId, c.Score,  c.RN, c.reverseRN, 
   case when r.SpecialCummSum + c.Score >= 0 then r.SpecialCummSum + c.Score else 0 end
  from RCTE r
  join CTE c on c.UserId = r.UserId AND c.RN = r.RN + 1
)
select UserId, SpecialCummSum as Score
from RCTE
where reverseRN = 1
order by UserId;
```

Is it a large table?
Then it might be worth it to first load the data into a temporary table.   One that has primary key with an IDENTITY.
Because the Recursive CTE can benefit from the index on the primary key.

**For example:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpScores') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpScores;
CREATE TABLE #tmpScores ( 
  ID int identity(1,1) primary key, 
  UserID int, 
  Score int,
  RN int,
  ReverseRN int
);

insert into #tmpScores 
(UserId, Score, RN, ReverseRN)
select UserId, Score,
row_number() over (partition by UserID order by RatingID) as RN,
row_number() over (partition by UserID order by RatingID desc) as reverseRN
from Scores
order by UserId, RatingID;

;with RCTE as
(
  select ID, UserId, Score, RN, reverseRN, iif(Score>=0,Score,0) as SpecialCummSum
  from #tmpScores 
  where RN = 1

  union all

  select t.ID, t.UserId, t.Score, t.RN, t.reverseRN, 
   case when r.SpecialCummSum + t.Score >= 0 then r.SpecialCummSum + t.Score else 0 end
  from RCTE r
  join #tmpScores t 
     on t.ID = r.ID + 1 AND t.UserId = r.UserId
     -- Using ID since it has an index and is sequencial without gaps
)
select UserId, SpecialCummSum as Score
from RCTE
where reverseRN = 1
order by UserId;
```

Comment: this is good but if the first x scores are a negative then this doesn't account for the rebase to zero. Any ideas?

Comment: @CR41G14: Don't only copy the query, but try to understand what it does. If you had understood it already, you would probably have got the solution at once: Replace `Score` in `select ID, UserId, Score, RN, reverseRN, Score as SpecialCummSum from CTE` with `case when Score >= 0 then Score else 0 end`.

Comment: @CR41G14 T.K. is right. In the RCTE the first query is the initiation of the recursion. So just initiate the score as 0 if it's negative there.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#retyy') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #retyy

CREATE TABLE #retyy (
    ident INT identity(1, 1),
    [UserID] INT,
    [Score] INT
    )
    insert into #retyy([UserID], [Score])
select * from (VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (1, -8),
    (1, 6),
    (2, 3))a([UserID], [Score])


   select [UserID],score from(SELECT [UserID],
        iif(score < 0, 0, score + isnull((
                    iif(lag(score) OVER (
                            PARTITION BY [UserID] ORDER BY ident
                            ) < 0, 0, lag(score) OVER (
                            PARTITION BY [UserID] ORDER BY ident
                            ))
                    ), 0)) score
,row_number() over (partition by [UserID] order by ident desc) rn
    FROM #retyy) a where rn=1
```

[link for the results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/359e0/7)

Comment: A point to note here, to get the desired output in the question, you would need to add a `row_number() over (partition by UserID order by ident desc)` and then wrap that query in a `select cols from subselect where RowNum = 1`

Comment: @iamdave - do you want to submit an answer?

Comment: I have updated the query.....got curious "Doesn't work this.." what you meant by saying this one

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Smart003 answer, to get to the actual output required in the question, filtering needs to be applied to only select the last row of each `UserId` running total:

```
declare @t table(RatingID int,UserID int,Score int)
insert into @t values
 (1,1,2 ) 
,(2,1,3 ) 
,(3,1,-8) 
,(4,1,6 )
,(5,2,3 )
;


select UserId
        ,Score
from(
    select RatingID
        ,UserID
        ,case when score < 0
                then 0
                else score+isnull(case when lag(score) over (partition by UserID order by RatingID) < 0
                                        then 0
                                        else lag(score) over (partition by [UserID] order by RatingID)
                                        end
                                ,0)
                end as Score
        ,row_number() over (partition by UserId order by RatingID desc) as rn
    from @t
) a
where rn = 1;
```

Output:

```
+--------+-------+
| UserId | Score |
+--------+-------+
|      1 |     6 |
|      2 |     3 |
+--------+-------+
```